# Segmentation fault (core dumped), cant figure why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, undefined-behavior, string-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    string cipher = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    string plaintext = "Hello World!";
    string ciphertext = "ciphertext: ";
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
    {
        if(isupper(plaintext[j]))
        {
            int k = plaintext[j] - 65;
            char append = toupper(cipher[k]);
            strncat(ciphertext, &append, 1);
        }
        else if(islower(plaintext[j]))
        {
            int l = plaintext[j] - 65;
            char append2 = tolower(cipher[l]);
            strncat(ciphertext, &append2, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            char append3 = plaintext[j];
            strncat(ciphertext, &append3, 1);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", ciphertext);
}
```

When running the above the error comes from trying to concatenate ciphertext and append. From what I can gather the error appears when trying to write to invalid memory location, I don't understand how this calls an invalid memory location?

Comment: Could you edit the question with the errors?

Comment: `ciphertext` is (a) a string literal, so it is read-only, and (b) even if it were writable, it has no space for concatenating other strings, especially ones that aren't even terminated strings and rather addresses of single character variables. Most of this is frankly the fault of harvard for foolishly type aliasing `string` to be `char *`, the ensuing confusion of which ultimately driving many a CS student to alcohol.

Comment: Again the dreadful CS50 `string` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer to a string literal

```
string ciphertext = "ciphertext: ";
```

and then you are trying to change the string literal

```
strncat(ciphertext, &append, 1);
```

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate a character array large enough to store concatenated strings as for example

```
char ciphertext[25] = "ciphertext: ";
```

Also in this if statement

```
    else if(islower(plaintext[j]))
    {
        int l = plaintext[j] - 65;
        char append2 = tolower(cipher[l]);
        //...
```

there is incorrectly calculated an index in the string `cipher`. You should not use magic numbers like 65. At least use characters like `'a'` or `'A'`.